# How to use list as parameters

Tags: clojure

I am new to Clojure so this question may be trivial:

Suppose you have a list `(\h \e \l \l \o)` and you want to use it as the actual parameters when calling a function, for example, `str` in order to get the same result as:

```
(str \h \e \l \l \o)
```

I came to a solution using eval:

```
(def paramlist '(\h \e \l \l \o))
(eval (conj paramlist str))
```

But I understand that is quite dirty and over killing the problem. What is the best solution to do this?

Comment: It is duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523254/passing-list-of-variables-individually-to-clojure-function

Comment: -1, Lacks effort. This question can be also easily Googled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [apply](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply)

```
user=> (apply str '(1 2 3 4))
"1234"
```