# Clojure: Transforming Varargs But Keeping them Varargs

Tags: clojure, variadic-functions

I am working on a little pet project in Clojure.  I have a function that I pass varargs:

```
(defn foor [bar & args]
  (let new-args (custom-transform args)]
    (do-something new-args))))))
```

But, `do-something` is expecting varargs, not a list object.  In `custom-transform`

```
(defn custom-transform [& args]
    (if vars vars nil))
```

How do I preserve the "vararg"-iness of my args after applying a transformation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing list of variables individually to clojure function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523254/passing-list-of-variables-individually-to-clojure-function)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clojure: How to Preserve Variadic Args Between Function Calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061503/clojure-how-to-preserve-variadic-args-between-function-calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think apply should do the trick:

```
(apply do-something new-args)
```

Your problem isn't specific to varargs. What you want to do is to call `do-something`, passing the elements of an array as the arguments to the function. This happens to be precisely what `apply` does.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick.  Thank you.  I need to wait 1 minute to accept

Comment: Btw, thanks for the solve, can you please explain why this works?  What is the rationale?

Comment: -1 This kind of question has been asked thousand times, and yet people ask it and someone put one line answer about `apply`. I don't get it. Examples: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621696/how-to-use-list-as-parameters) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523254/passing-list-of-variables-individually-to-clojure-function) (this is oldest question of this kind).

Comment: good point, Mark. I should have thought to look for dupes. Sorry!

Comment: Glad you guys worked that out.  But all of those posts dont really explain the rationale.  Can you explain this in a basic way for those who are new to the language?

Comment: If you write `(f [1 2 3])`, a single vector argument gets passed to f. `apply` takes its second argument and passes the things in it to its first argument as separate arguments, so `(apply f [1 2 3])` is equivalent to `(f 1 2 3)`. In your case the arguments happen to be in a variable, not a vector literal, but the principle is the same. Does that help? Can you point to something in specific that I could clarify further?

Comment: Thats great thanks.  Do you know about passing varargs to another function and preserving there varargness?  Example `(def foo [& args]) (def bar [& args] (foo args))`