# Clojure: How to Preserve Variadic Args Between Function Calls

Tags: clojure, variadic-functions

I have two variadic functions.  One of them passes its arguments to the other.  The problem is that the varargs are becoming a list on the second call.  How do I keep them varargs?

```
=> (defn foo [x & ys] (println x ys))
=> (defn bar [x & ys] (foo (clojure.string/upper-case x) ys))
=> (foo "hi")  
hi nil
=> (bar "hi")
HI (nil)
```

In the real function, foo passes its args to a variadic java function, so the varargs really need to stay varargs.  How do I do this?

Comment: What are you asking here that is different that the other question you just asked, http://stackoverflow.com/q/26021785/1756702?

Comment: Yes, `apply` is the answer here as well. And you will want `into-array` in order to make that Java method invocation (varargs are a Java compiler thing, Clojure does not use the Java compiler, in the jvm it just uses an array as the last arg)

Comment: So something like this? `(apply identity ys)` I want to pass them as is, so I think its a little different that the question I asked about transforming them but keeping them varargs, that was within one function.

Comment: I tried `(apply identity ys)` in `bar` but I got this `ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: core/identity  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)`

Comment: Java varargs *are* an array. That's all they _ever_ are. There's no non-array thing varargs in Java can ever be. "Keeping them varargs" is not a question that makes any sense, because _they never are anything but an array_ (with a little syntactic sugar in the Java compiler which the Clojure compiler doesn't provide or honor) _in the first place_.

Comment: ...whereas Clojure destructuring (not varargs!) provides a _sequence_. Not all sequences are arrays, so you might need to but the sequence's contents _into_ an array, but again, there is no "varargs" thing that something is getting converted to or from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply

> ;you can also put operands before the list of operands and they'll be
>   consumed in the list of operands   (apply + 1 2 '(3 4))  ; equal to
>   (apply + '(1 2 3 4))
>   => 10

So

```
(defn bar [x & ys] (apply foo (clojure.string/upper-case x) ys))
```

should work.
For your problem with Java varargs note noisesmith's comment.